# Cannot set property for Model class in Laravel

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, model, laravel-6

I'm trying add dependency injection on User class and after few hours trying, I found this way:

- I added this code to `App\Models\User` class

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roleService = resolve(RoleService::class);
    }
```

- I've checked `$this->roleService` value, it work normally, buut when I try to use it in a function:

```
    public function isAdmin() {
        return $this->roleService->isAdmin($this->role_id);
    }
```

- This function throw an error `Call to a member function isAdmin() on null`. When I logged `$this->roleService`, it returned `null`.

Anyone can solve this?

Comment: Have you declared `protected $roleService;` variable before your constructor ? Also don't you think your constructor should be like this `public function __construct(User $user)` and then `$this->roleService = $user;` ?

Comment: + I tried to declare ```$roleService``` and it doesn't work. I think it isn't matter because I've tried to remove it on other class and it worked normally.
+ If I modify constructor to ```public function __construct(User $user)```, it probably throw error because constructor of Model parent class initialized with 1 parameter like this ```__construct(array $attributes = array())```

Comment: Can you please dd this `dd( $this->roleService)` in isAdmin() and in __construct()

Comment: using in ```__construct()``` returned instance of ```RoleService``` class but using in ```isAdmin()``` return ```null```

Comment: That's great that you've resolved it, could you update your answer with code which you've refactored ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm doing it and getting stuck for hours :D

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom accessor for your model, and get/set the value from there.

```
public function getRoleServiceAttribute ()
{
    if(is_null($this->roleService)){
        $this->roleService = resolve(RoleService::class);
    }

    return $this->roleService;
}
```

Then you can access the attribute as `$this->role_service`

Also make sure you declare the `$roleService` class property as protected, to avoid accidental access as `$this->roleService` from anywhere else.

Comment: it doesn't work. Error ```Call to a member function find() on null``` returned.

Comment: can you access it via User::find(1)->roleService?

Comment: No, it return ```null``` value.

Comment: I have updated my answer, check if it works for you.

Comment: it doesn't work. It throw an error ```Undefined property: App\Models\User::$roleService```

Comment: When you are accessing it, you should access it like `$this->role_service`

Answer (score 0):

Thank for help. I just have referenced answer of an expert. He said that we should not dependency injection in `Model` class because it will broke project structure. Project should be followed structure: `Controller`->`Service`->`Repository`->`Model`->`Database`. So, I'll refactor my code follow it.